# Nyc coverage is not working for me when using functional approach with e.g. ramda

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, functional-programming, ramda.js, nyc

So my code is this:

```js
const handler = (event = { body: {} }) => {
  if (isEventEmpty(event)) {
    return Promise.resolve({})
  }
  const getPayload = R.compose(
    R.flatten,
    R.map(x => transformRecord(x)),
    R.pluck('Stuff'),
    R.path(['body'])
  )
  const processEvent = R.compose(
    toPromise,
    R.ifElse(isEventEmpty, R.always({}), getPayload)
  )
  return processEvent(event)
}

module.exports = { handler }
```

With `if (isEventEmpty(event)) {` coverage is 66.67% which is fine. But without that `if` coverage will be 0. Notice that I use `R.ifElse` composable from Ramda. All unit tests pass that's why I'm not showing them, but coverage report shows `0% Branches 0/1`. With imperative `if` branch I have 2/3 in coverage report.

Does anyone have also experience NOT using if-else branching (or loops) when writing their code? Seems that `nyc` is only looking in if-else, for/while branches or I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think code coverage isn't working, it is simply becoming less useful in a functional programming setting.

This is what I've shared in a presentation at work:

Given `yes-no.js`:

```js
module.exports = bool => bool === true ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

And `yes-no-fp.js`

```js
const {ifElse, equals, always} = require('ramda');

module.exports = ifElse(equals(true),always('yes'),always('no'));
```

And the following tests:

```js
test.true(yesOrNo(true) === 'yes');
test.true(yesOrNoFp(true) === 'yes');
```

Then you get the following code coverage:

[image]

As you can see for the same test:

1. The functional programming version reports 100% branch coverage
2. The "imperative" version reports 50% branch coverage

Personally I think this is a good thing as I always say this to my team mates: code coverage is a tool not a rule. It should help you devise fewer but better tests. It should never be an aim.

If 100% code coverage is your aim then there is a chance that nobody in code review will flag that you're missing a test case. Why should they if you have successfully covered the entire code?

---

*So how do you write better tests?*

I'm not sure there's a single answer to that question but I'd definitely recommend that you look into property-based testing. It can help you write more thorough tests for sure.

If you're interested I found this [article](https://medium.com/javascript-inside/generative-testing-in-javascript-f91432247c27) extremely useful.

Comment: That's a great answer.  I suspected something like that, but I'd never spent the time to check it.  I've worked in places where managers try to use code coverage as a cudgel: "This team has to hit 90% code coverage... and by next month!"  And I'm usually in a position to push back: "Code coverage is a tool for developers.  That broad number is meaningless; it's only the detailed reports of what branches are not covered that matter."  Sometimes they hear it, sometimes they don't.  Abstraction (like using a library) will often *reduce* the number of tests necessary to hit some level of coverage.

Comment: Awesome.  More detailed answer I couldn't have asked :D Thank you so much, branch comparison is very helpful.